# I would like to know how to remove the NA part of my ggplot bargraph and add number labels to it

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm working with the "penguins" dataset from the following code from a github profile. I would like to evaluate the number of sex individuals from the islands by building a bar graph (geom_bar) that distributes the number of males and females in each island with a label providing the count number of males and females within the same 'island' category. Additionally, I've been struggling with trying to write a code block that removes the NA count from my legend and data visualization.

```
    install.packages("remotes")
    remotes::install_github("allisonhorst/palmerpenguins")
    library(palmerpenguins)

    ggplot(penguins, aes(island)) +
      geom_bar(aes(fill = sex), width = 0.5) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust= 0.6)) +
      labs(title = "All Accessible Penguin Sex Count",
           x = "island",
           y = "Number of Individuals",
           fill = "Sex")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop NAs by subsetting the dataframe and add number labels with geom_text, E.g.

```
ggplot(data = subset(penguins, !is.na(sex)),
       aes(x = island, fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 65, vjust= 0.6)) +
  labs(title = "All Accessible Penguin Sex Count",
       x = "island",
       y = "Number of Individuals",
       fill = "Sex")
```

Comment: Thank you Jared, you are blessing. The code solves exactly what I was struggling with. Cheers mate!